# "Learn sql the hard way" - Exercise 13 : Trouble with a nested select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I was going through "Learn SQL the hard way" and I am currently in exercise 13.

I am stuck in the part where we have to

> Write a query that can find all the names of pets and their owners
>   bought after 2004. Key to this is to map the person_pet based on the
>   purchased_on column to the pet and parent.

My tables look like this

```
sqlite> select * from person ; 
id          first_name  last_name   age         dead        phone_number  salary      dob       
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ------------  ----------  ----------
0           john        doe         20          0           9929          123123.0    2015-12-09
1           foo         bar         25          0           12            123123.0    2004-12-11
2           michal      jordan      19          0           12            123123.0    2005-12-11
3           tom         ford        30          0           12            123123.0    2002-12-11
```

And

```
sqlite> select * from pet ; 
id          name        breed       age         dead        dob         parent_id 
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           fluffy      Unicorn     5           0           2012-02-01            
1           quora       social net  10          0           2010-02-01            
2           Goldie      German She  6           0           2009-02-01            
3           boxer       golden ret  3           0           2007-02-01            
4           naman       kutta       10          1           2011-02-01            
5           hari        ohk         7           0           2015-02-01


sqlite> select * from person_pet ; 
person_id   pet_id      purchased_on
----------  ----------  ------------
2           2           2002-03-30  
2           3           2001-04-30  
2           4           2005-04-30  
2           5           2003-04-30  
3           1           2006-04-30  
3           4           2005-04-30
```

My `schema` looks like this

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE person(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
 first_name TEXT,
 last_name TEXT, 
 age INTEGER
, dead INTEGER, phone_number INTEGER, salary FLOAT, dob DATETIME);
CREATE TABLE pet(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
 name TEXT, 
 breed TEXT, 
 age INTEGER, 
 dead INTEGER
, dob DATETIME, parent_id INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE person_pet(
 person_id INTEGER, 
 pet_id INTEGER
, purchased_on DATETIME);
CREATE TABLE cars(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 car_name TEXT
);
```

**What I have tried**

I am able to get the `person_id` and `pet_id` brought after the year "2004" with the query

```
sqlite> select person_id, pet_id, purchased_on from person_pet 
   ...> where purchased_on > "2004-01-01" ;
person_id   pet_id      purchased_on
----------  ----------  ------------
2           4           2005-04-30  
3           1           2006-04-30  
3           4           2005-04-30
```

How should I proceed to get the names out now ?

This is my first time with SQL so any help would be much appreciated. Been stuck in this for a while.

**Edit** :

I got to know that this can be done using `joins` but as it has not been covered till Exercise 13. How can we do this without using `joins` ?

As @vkp asked in the comments, `in` has been covered till now.

Comment: `join` it to `person` table

Comment: Any other way than joins @vkp ?

Comment: You need to use joins. Here is a great article explaining them. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/?_sm_au_=iHV1t6nnZDWZZPsq Also, you have really poor datatypes in your tables. You should not use text as it has been deprecated since sql server 2005 in favor of varchar(max). But for names you should find a reasonable length. Also, the float datatype is an approximate datatype and probably shouldn't be used when you want exact precision. You should instead use a numeric.

Comment: Please, only tag products involved. (MS SQL Server and SQLite aren't fully compatible.)

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your input. Going through the blog now.

Comment: @SeanLange Removing the tag `sql-server` now

Comment: If you can't use a join, think about subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the IDs with their associated names, you could use [correlated subqueries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
select (select first_name
        from person
        where id = person_pet.person_id),
       (select name
        from pet
        where id = person_pet.pet_id),
       purchased_on
from person_pet
where purchased_on >= '2005';
```

(When you need to get multiple columns from the same table (e.g., first name and last name), this is less efficient than a join.)

Comment: Works perfectly. I  Added aliases for the columns for better clarity in output. Can you point me to some blog/article which explains about `Correlated subqueries`?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to `join` the other two tables as well.

```
select pp.person_id, pp.pet_id, pp.purchased_on, pt.name, p.first_name, p.last_name 
from person_pet pp
inner join person p on p.id = pp.person_id
inner join pet pt on pt.id = pp.pet_id
where purchased_on > "2004-01-01"
```

Comment: Works but can you show me how to do it without using joins? As joins has not been covered till Exercise 13, there must be an alternative right? Many thanks but!

Comment: has `in` been covered?

Comment: The date literal should be enclosed in single-quotes, not double-quotes (although SQLite probably is lenient enough to allow it).

Comment: @vkp Yes. `in` has been covered.

Comment: Have carthesian products been covered? has EXISTS been covered ?

Comment: @prodicus..i can't think of a way with out using a `join`. will try and post if i can think of one

Comment: @prodicus Joins were covered in exercise 6.

Comment: @joop `EXISTS` have been covered but I am not sure what do you mean by carthesian products

Comment: @CL `JOIN` was just mentioned over in the portability notes at the end of the exercise as another way of doing the aforementioned exercise but an explanation was not provided. You might wanna recheck it here http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex6.html

Comment: @prodicus What is shown in exercise 6 *is* a join, only with a different syntax. And regardless what you choose to call it, you can use the same mechanism in exercise 13.

Comment: @CL Ohk. But don't joins have a syntax in the lines of `inner join` as in the answer by @vkp? I may be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

While this is backward, to say the least, it should work:

```
select person_id, (select max(first_name)+' '+max(last_name) from person where id = person_id) as person_name, pet_id, (select max(name) from pet where id = pet_id) as pet_name, purchased_on from person_pet 
   ...> where purchased_on > "2004-01-01" ;
```

PS - using IN will not help, since you have to get data from two extra tables. If it was only one extra table, it would have worked nicely.

PPS - [this](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex6.html) is basically a join. Try using that too.

Comment: It's showing `0.0` for each of the values in `person_name`. Can you check the query again @Mihai. Many thanks.

Comment: Are the values in pet_name ok?